# Difficulty in an interference problem

Tags: homework-and-exercises, interference

I have trouble with this problem:

"On the shore of a sea there's a radio telescope that follows a star ascending over the horizon. Because of the interference of the reflection from the sea the signal gets stronger until the star is 30 degrees over the horizon. What is the height of the telescope from the sea level if the wavelength of the radio signal is 80 meters?"

Here's my picture of the situation:

[image] 
With a little trigonometry you can calculate the phase difference of the signals to be 
$$d= x(1-\cos (2\alpha ))$$
and when the signal is at it's strongest that should be a multiple of the wavelength:
$$x(1-\cos (2\alpha )) = n\lambda, n\in\mathbb{N} ,$$
from which calculating the height is simple trigonometry again.

**The question is:** How should I know what the $n$ is? It would be nice to think it's $1$, since the signal hasn't reached other maxima during the rise of the star, but if the wording of the problem is the reason to pick $n=1$, then it should be also observed that the interference for small $\alpha$:s is constructive and becomes more destructive as $d\to \lambda /2$, after that increasing again.

This is *a sort of* homework that I have already returned, and the only feedback I've got, or ever will get, is that it's wrong. I won't go into details why it's so. I'm just curious, since I can't figure this out.

One possible explanation could be that the signal doesn't reflect like in the picture for small angles $\alpha$. However this makes the situation even worse for choosing the right $n$, since the first maximas for big $n$:s come in even smaller angles than the minimum in the case $n=1$.

If someone can spot why it's wrong, please tell me. :)

Comment: I think the path difference should be $\frac{1}{2} {\lambda}$ as you get a phase change of pi at the reflection with the water surface.

Answer (score 0):

To expand on my comment:
From your equations, if we let h be the height of the dish above the water, then we have $x\sin{\alpha}=h$, then for constructive interference we get 
$\frac{h}{\sin{\alpha}}(1-\cos{2\alpha})=\frac{(2n+1)(\lambda)}{2}$. This simplifies to $\frac{(2n+1)(\lambda)}{2}=2h\sin{\alpha}$, and we see that as $\alpha$ increases from zero the first value for which constructive interference occurs is $\frac{\lambda}{2}=2h\sin{\alpha}$.

Comment: That seems to be the problem. I was completely unaware of the phase shift. Thank you. :)